# How to stop event propagation in jQuery click function inside click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having troubles stopping click event propagation. I have a click function inside another click function.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

1. Select a label by clicking it
2. Then click inside the box to determine which label was clicked

This works fine if you select labels one by one. But if you click on Label 1 and then Label 2, both events are recorded (see console log). Or if you click on Label 1 five times and then click inside the box, all five events are captured.

How can I stop this event propagation?

**JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q930bvff**

```js
var objectName, currentObject;
$('.label').click(function(event) {

  $('.label').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  objectName = $(this).attr('id');
  currentObject = $(this).hasClass('selected');
  
 
  if (currentObject) {
    $('#box').one('click', function(e) {
      console.log(objectName);
    });
  }
 
 event.stopPropagation();
 
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: 'Helvetica', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.label {
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.label.selected {
  background: green;
}

#box {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="label-1" class="label">Label 1</div>
<div id="label-2" class="label">Label 2</div>
<div id="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$('#box').off("click")` before every new `.one("click"` to kill all the previously created `click` handlers on `#box`.

See working snippet below:

```js
var objectName, currentObject;
$('.label').click(function(event) {

  $('.label').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  objectName = $(this).attr('id');
  currentObject = $(this).hasClass('selected');
  
 
  if (currentObject) {
    $('#box').off("click").one('click', function(e) {
      console.log(objectName);
    });
  }
 
 event.stopPropagation();
 
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: 'Helvetica', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.label {
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.label.selected {
  background: green;
}

#box {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="label-1" class="label">Label 1</div>
<div id="label-2" class="label">Label 2</div>
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: Nooo. **Don't** `.off("click")` all (`"click"` in this case) events bound to an element. The same way we recycle garbage thinking of our grandchildren so we should assign **namespaces to our events** as developers. - If a developer, tomorrow or in N years assigns a `click` handler to `#box` that detaches a car from it's holding capsule, the same would not happen since it was ***off-ed*** thanks to your `.off("click")`. [Issue demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e44gf403/), and [how to be leaders in our business demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e44gf403/1/)